# Redux Forms object in select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I've created a redux-form in which I want to submit a couple of text inputs and one select where the selected item is an object. However, after submitting I don't receive the correct object but some kind of reference '[object object]' ..

**Render for the select:**

```
const renderSelectField = ({input, options, meta: {touched, error}}) => (
  <select className='form-control' {...input}>
    <option></option>
    {options.map(option =>
    <option key={option.id} value={option}>{option.name}</option>
    )}
  </select>
)
```

**In the form itself:**

```
<div className='form-group'>
  <label>Category</label>
  <div>
    <Field name='category' component={renderSelectField} options={this.props.categories.categories}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The submit handler in my parent component:**

```
handleSubmit(values, dispatch) {
    var asset = {
      name: values['name'],
      vendor: values['vendor'],
      version: values['version'],
      technology: values['technology'],
      category: values['category']
    }

    return dispatch(addAsset(asset))
      .then((result) => {
        if(result.type == ADD_ASSET_FAILURE){
        }
        if(result.type == ADD_ASSET_SUCCESS){
          dispatch(routerActions.push('/assets'))
        }
      })
  }
```

**And what is being submitted:**

[image: Error]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use object as value in `option`. It must be string. 
Like this:

```
<option key={option.id} value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
```

Comment: Alright I tried doing that. The problem is I can't reach or get access to the object I want then. If I use a function, getCategoryById, I always get set form submitted false.

Comment: You need to find object in source array by id that you will get from `values['category']`. Try method `find` of array.